# How to enable the command 'CorePlot' in Cocoa Pods?

Tags: ruby, xcode, core-plot, cocoapods

When I tried to install CorePlot to my iOS project on xcode via Cocoa Pods, the following massage showed up. Could any of you guys give me any advice to solve this issue? Thanks.

```
xxxxx-MacBook-Pro:Test1 xxxxx$ pod 'CorePlot', '~> 1.5' # CorePlot
[!] Unknown command: `CorePlot,`
Did you mean: repo
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to install this pod by running `pod` from the command line. What you need to do is put your `pod` definitions in a `Podfile` in the root of your repo. After doing this you need to run `pod install`. Check out the using CocoaPods guide for more info:

http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html

Comment: Thanks so much, that perfectly solved the problem and made my day! :)
@Keith Smiley